# Create repo from multiple Git bundle files

Tags: git, git-bundle

I have received multiple Git bundle files and would like to combine all them into one repository.

I know that the command `git clone myfile.bundle` will create a repo from the bundle file which I could then merge together with all the other files. Is there was a way of combining multiple bundle files?

Comment: How do you intend to combine them? Do their histories go end-to-end? Do they contain different files? Do you want to merge three separate branches into one?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all bundles comes from the same Git repo you can pull from them like you pull from remote repos:

```
git pull bundle-file branch
```

Make sure to pull them in order. Otherwise you will get error messages about missing start commits.